# Modal popup doesn't get called

Tags: javascript, popup, modal-dialog

I'm using [this article](http://javascript.about.com/library/blmodald1.htm) to implement a modal popup.
I added everything, and when I use a button on the html page and using `<span class="dialink" onclick="sm('box',200,50)">` the popup works.
But i want the popup to be opened by a JS call, this is the code i used to call the function :

```
var x = document.createElement('script');
x.src = '/popup/modaldbox.js';
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(x);
// Open popup
sm('box',200,50);
```

I've tried also when the article suggests but with no luck :

```
var x = document.createElement('script');
x.src = '/popup/modaldbox.js';
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(x);
// Open popup
var z = 'something to check';
$('txt').innerHTML = z;

function OKSelected() {
    var y = z;
}
```

I've checked the path to the JS is correct, this is not the problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using inline script you should better use an event listener.

```
<span class="dialink" onclick="sm('box',200,50)">
```

To attach an event listener you can do:

```
<span class="dialink">

<script type="text/javascript">

// Javascript
var dialink = document.querySelector('.dialink');
dialink.addEventListener('click', function () {
    sm('box', 200, 50);
});

// jQuery
var $dialink = $('.dialink');
$dialink.on('click', {param: 'box', param2: 200, param3: 50}, sm);

</script>
```

If you want that the dialog box opens without any user interaction then your first example should be alright.

Besides that have you checked the developer console in your browser if it throws any erros?